# Placing label descriptions below input elements

Tags: css, flexbox, uikit

What I am trying to achieve visually:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DQPi.jpg

What I have the closest approximation of: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzQLQw

Now to place the descriptions below the checkboxes, I could add a class `uk-flex-column` like so: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKQGWd

to the parent div of the input elements to force column stacking.

This works fine as long as the the window is not being resized to a smaller width.

If it is resized then the content in the columns changes their position and the chekboxes no longer stay on the strikethrough line.

What could I do to force the checkboxes to stay on the line when the window is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following CSS:

```
.strikethrough {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 40px;
left: 0px;
height: 5px;
background: gainsboro;
z-index: -1;
}
```

By putting the top to a fixed pixel height and not a percentage, it should stay aligned even when resizing the window.